# Control Trinamic motor using ros_canopen

Tags: ros, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to control [Trinamic PD-1160](http://www.trinamic.com/products/pandrives/pandrives-stepper/pd-1160) motor using ros_canopen. The motor is DS402 complient. The CANopen manual of this motor is located [here](http://www.trinamic.com/_scripts/download.php?file=_articles%2Fproducts%2Fpandrives%2Fpd-1160%2F_documentation%2FTMCM-1180_1160_1140_CANopen_manual.pdf).
I have configured the canopen_motor_node using the following [eds and yaml files](https://gist.github.com/JuliusGel/fb6d800400899759ec1574904921b9a6).

The canopen_motor_node starts successfully using this configuration file but initialization service fails with the following error:

```
Transition timeout; Could not enable motor; Transition timeout
```

Here is a short snippet of candump output that I get when initializing the canopen_motor_node:

```
can0  000   [2]  82 01
can0  701   [1]  00
can0  601   [8]  2B 17 10 00 00 00 00 00
can0  581   [8]  60 17 10 00 00 00 00 00
can0  601   [8]  40 41 60 00 00 00 00 00
can0  581   [8]  4B 41 60 00 18 06 00 00
can0  601   [8]  40 61 60 00 00 00 00 00
can0  581   [8]  4F 61 60 00 00 00 00 00
can0  601   [8]  40 64 60 00 00 00 00 00
can0  581   [8]  43 64 60 00 00 00 00 00
can0  601   [8]  40 6C 60 00 00 00 00 00
can0  581   [8]  43 6C 60 00 00 00 00 00
can0  601   [8]  40 44 60 00 00 00 00 00
can0  581   [8]  4B 44 60 00 00 00 00 00
can0  601   [8]  40 40 60 00 00 00 00 00
can0  581   [8]  4B 40 60 00 00 00 00 00
can0  601   [8]  40 FF 60 00 00 00 00 00
can0  581   [8]  43 FF 60 00 00 00 00 00
can0  000   [2]  01 01
can0  181   [2]  18 06
can0  281   [3]  18 06 00
can0  601   [8]  40 01 10 00 00 00 00 00
can0  581   [8]  4F 01 10 00 00 00 00 00
can0  601   [8]  40 01 10 00 00 00 00 00
can0  581   [8]  4F 01 10 00 00 00 00 00
can0  301   [3]  00 00 00
can0  081   [8]  20 63 01 00 FF 00 00 00
can0  080   [0] 
can0  381   [6]  18 06 00 00 00 00
can0  000   [2]  02 01
```

From this I see that the first control word and operation mode is all 00 (message 301). The motor responds with emergency message to this. From the motors documentation this error message is:

```
Parameter error
The data in the received PDO is either wrong or cannot be accepted due to the
internal state of the drive.
```

My question is weather this is a configuration issue or a bug in ros_canopen. The motor documentation has a section describing that in order to move the motor its operation mode has to be changed first and only then the state switching should occur. Note that I have changed the switching_state parameter to 2 but this did not have any effect on init function behavior.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236140/control-trinamic-motor-using-ros_canopen/) by [JuliusGel](https://answers.ros.org/users/20679/juliusgel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 433 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> (from the manual:)
> The motor will not run when the operating mode is set to 0. It will be stopped when the motor is running in one of the
> supported operating modes and the operating mode is then switched to 0

> Note that I have changed the switching_state parameter to 2 but this did not have any effect on init function behavior.

I don't think this is necessary, at least I don't find the requirement in the manual at a first glance.
The mode 0 in the PDO message does not correspond to mode switch, but to the default value in the EDS.
(Your config couples the control word and the mode in one PDO, so both get sent)

If you want to set the initial value, just add a `ParameterValue` with a specific mode to your EDS/DCF.
Or use the `dcf_overlay` feature for convenience (http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_chain_node?distro=indigo#CA-aac0b244a9b279b10a86af0a165ff7215371ab50_4).
This way `6060` gets written before the start-up and any PDO.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JuliusGel](https://answers.ros.org/users/20679/juliusgel/) on 2016-06-07**:
Adding ParameterValue to 6060 and 6040 helped to get rid of 081 emergency message. The problem is that I still get the same error: Transition timeout; Could not enable motor; Transition timeout. Maybe you know what other issues I might have?

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2016-06-07**:
Hard to tell.
Please add an updated log (at gist?).

**Comment by [JuliusGel](https://answers.ros.org/users/20679/juliusgel/) on 2016-06-07**:
I have updated the eds and added updated candump [here](https://gist.github.com/JuliusGel/fb6d800400899759ec1574904921b9a6)

**Comment by [JuliusGel](https://answers.ros.org/users/20679/juliusgel/) on 2016-06-29**:
We have found the issue, the main problem was that at the moment ros_canopen does not allow to map the same object in multiple PDO. Related issue [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/issues/183).